# unable to build new java spring project

Tags: java, spring, ant, build

i am trying to build a simple java spring project i got setup which contains my hibernate .hbm mappings, the POJO'S that go with each mappings and one SimpleFormController class that looks like this:

```
package com.jr.user.controller;

import org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.SimpleFormController;

public class RegisterNewUser extends SimpleFormController{

}
```

Its empty as you can see but when i try to build it i get the following error below:

> BUILD FAILED
>   C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxxxxx\Work\Online
>   Racing League\build.xml:45: Unable to
>   find a javac compiler;
>   com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the
>   classpath. Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not
>   point to the JDK. It is currently set
>
> to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6"
>
> Total time: 237 milliseconds

Also, whats weird is that the package line on the above code is highlighted in a red underline indicating a syntax or code error and when i mouse over to that line, this is what it says:

> The type javax.portlet.PortletContext
>   cannot be resolved. It is indirectly
>   referenced from required .class files

My build.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project name="Online Racing League" basedir="." default="usage">
    <property file="build.properties"/>

    <property name="src.dir" value="src"/>
    <property name="web.dir" value="war"/>
    <property name="build.dir" value="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/classes"/>
    <property name="name" value="Online Racing League"/>

    <path id="master-classpath">
        <fileset dir="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/lib">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <!-- We need the servlet API classes: -->
        <!--  * for Tomcat 5/6 use servlet-api.jar -->
        <!--  * for other app servers - check the docs -->
        <fileset dir="${appserver.lib}">
            <include name="servlet*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <pathelement path="${build.dir}"/>
    </path>

    <target name="usage">
        <echo message=""/>
        <echo message="${name} build file"/>
        <echo message="-----------------------------------"/>
        <echo message=""/>
        <echo message="Available targets are:"/>
        <echo message=""/>
        <echo message="build     --> Build the application"/>
        <echo message="deploy    --> Deploy application as directory"/>
        <echo message="deploywar --> Deploy application as a WAR file"/>
        <echo message="install   --> Install application in Tomcat"/>
        <echo message="reload    --> Reload application in Tomcat"/>
        <echo message="start     --> Start Tomcat application"/>
        <echo message="stop      --> Stop Tomcat application"/>
        <echo message="list      --> List Tomcat applications"/>
        <echo message=""/>
    </target>

    <target name="build" description="Compile main source tree java files">
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
        <javac destdir="${build.dir}" source="1.5" target="1.5" debug="true"
               deprecation="false" optimize="false" failonerror="true">
            <src path="${src.dir}"/>
            <classpath refid="master-classpath"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="deploy" depends="build" description="Deploy application">
        <copy todir="${deploy.path}/${name}" preservelastmodified="true">
            <fileset dir="${web.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.*"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>

    <target name="deploywar" depends="build" description="Deploy application as a WAR file">
        <war destfile="${deploy.path}/${name}.war"
             webxml="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml">
            <fileset dir="${web.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.*"/>
            </fileset>
        </war>
        <copy todir="${deploy.path}" preservelastmodified="true">
            <fileset dir=".">
                <include name="*.war"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>



    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <!-- Tomcat tasks - remove these if you don't have Tomcat installed -->
    <!-- ============================================================== -->

        <path id="catalina-ant-classpath">
            <!-- We need the Catalina jars for Tomcat -->
            <!--  * for other app servers - check the docs -->
            <fileset dir="${appserver.lib}">
                <include name="catalina-ant.jar"/>
            </fileset>
        </path>

        <taskdef name="install" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask">
            <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
        </taskdef>
        <taskdef name="reload" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ReloadTask">
            <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
        </taskdef>
        <taskdef name="list" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ListTask">
            <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
        </taskdef>
        <taskdef name="start" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StartTask">
            <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
        </taskdef>
        <taskdef name="stop" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StopTask">
            <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
        </taskdef>

        <target name="install" description="Install application in Tomcat">
            <install url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
                     username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
                     password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
                     path="/${name}"
                     war="${name}"/>
        </target>

        <target name="reload" description="Reload application in Tomcat">
            <reload url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
                     username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
                     password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
                     path="/${name}"/>
        </target>

        <target name="start" description="Start Tomcat application">
            <start url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
                     username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
                     password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
                     path="/${name}"/>
        </target>

        <target name="stop" description="Stop Tomcat application">
            <stop url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
                     username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
                     password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
                     path="/${name}"/>
        </target>

        <target name="list" description="List Tomcat applications">
            <list url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
                     username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
                     password="${tomcat.manager.password}"/>
        </target>

    <!-- End Tomcat tasks -->

    </project>
```

And my build properties is looks like this:

```
# Ant properties for building the springapp

appserver.home=C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 7.0
# for Tomcat 5 use $appserver.home}/server/lib
# for Tomcat 6 use $appserver.home}/lib
appserver.lib=${appserver.home}/lib/

deploy.path=${appserver.home}/webapps

tomcat.manager.url=http://localhost:8080/manager
tomcat.manager.username=
tomcat.manager.password=
```

Whats strange is that if i do not extend SimpleFormController . the error:

> The type javax.portlet.PortletContext
>   cannot be resolved. It is indirectly
>   referenced from required .class files

dissapears but i still fail to build it with the exact same error.

im currently using eclipse IDE and tomcat 7

I have the necessary libs needed to run spring and hibernate so i cant quite figure out whats the issue.

i checked the JAVA home path and my java is installed there correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Set your `JAVA_HOME` to JDK like  `c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\`

Comment: tried changing it but eclipse still points the JAVA_HOME to the same place as before. i double checked the path from Enviornemnt variables and my changes are saved. i will try and see if it will work when i do a reboot of my machine

Comment: Tried restarting eclipse and still says my JAVA_HOME is pointed to a JRE and not the JDK. im guessing a restart is required to do the job. im using windows 7 if that helps

Comment: Ok now i have restarted my pc and it sill says my JAVA_HOME is not set properly! i followed this example on how to change it.

Comment: have a look at [here](http://wso2.org/project/wsas/java/1.1/docs/setting-java-home.html)

Comment: Its more or less the same example that i posted.

Comment: Ok basically i have already tried the link you provided and the JAVA_HOME from eclipse still points to a JRE and not the JDK i specified from envrioment variables. I have also brought up the cm.exe window, typed in echo %JAVA_HOME% and it displays the correct JDK path

Comment: have you restarted eclipse after making change in env. variable ?

Comment: check in eclipse is there any variable with same name ? `windows>preference>java>build path>classpath variables`

Comment: I wish I could access your machine :)

Comment: Do you need anymore info? print screens of my directory structure? lib folder?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your JAVA_HOME environment variable points to a JRE (Java Runtime Environment), but you need it to point to a JDK (Java Development Kit).

Comment: I've pointed it properly by setting the enviornment variables but eclipse still ignores what i have specified there and points to a JRE. i tried restarting my computer and still no joy

Comment: I have also brought up the cm.exe window, typed in echo %JAVA_HOME% and it displays the correct path

Comment: @jonney Are you using an eclipse Run Configuration? Perhaps you should check the VM args you are using?

Comment: im basically right clicking on my build.xml and selecting "run as" So to answer your question i dont think i am.

Comment: @jonney yes you are. Run as... uses Run Configurations. Select `Run > Run Configurations` and you can find the configuration you are using

Comment: ok i checked my run configurations and under Enviornment Tab, there are now Variable and values set in a box labeled Enviornment variables to set: im guessing this is where my VM args are?

Comment: @jonney probably, yes, but this is going to far. please read this section: http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-running_and_debugging.htm

Comment: EDIT: ok so i added a new variable and value using JAVA_HOME as the variable and value = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\ and that diddnt work. eclipse still thinks my java_home is pointing to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6"

Answer (score 0):

Ok a small update. it now build fine and i did not have to do a single thing. i just opened the project and run the build.xml on  the SpringSource tool suite IDE which is another flavour of eclipse but spring based and it worked. the only thing is that the "package" line still is highlighted with an error but it still builds fine?

Very strange indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your PATH environment variable.
Just  put the version of Java you want before the Windows directory in your PATH.

```
set PATH="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_35\bin";%PATH%
```

On Windows, the java executable uses the Windows Registry to locate the default version of Java to run.
The copy of java.exe to run is found by using the PATH environment variable. Unless you take steps to change this, by default a copy will be found in the Windows directory. Since this copy isn't in a Java runtime directory, it locates one by looking at the registry.
So, you either need to modify the registry, or put the version of Java you want before the Windows directory in your PATH.